# Ошибка SSLHandshakeException при получении картинки

Tags: android, glide

При загрузке картинки с сайта по https ссылке, происходит ошибка. 
Использую Glide `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'`

Ошибка выходит на устройстве 4.4.4 (ниже версии не проверял).
На устройствах Android 6, 8, 9 - работает идеально.

Загрузка:

```
 Glide.with(icon.getContext())
                    .load(data.getImage())
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(icon);
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x6261eef0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
> error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x5a5f9d5c:0x00000000)
>     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448)
>     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
>     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
>     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
>     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
>     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:104)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:59)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:164)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:65)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:309)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
>  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x6261eef0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
> error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x5a5f9d5c:0x00000000)
>     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
> ```

Как можно исправить?

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002766/retrofit2-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-sslhandshakeexception-sslprotocolexception/1002779#1002779

Comment: СпасибО! Воспользовался методом обновления через ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это означает, что на устройстве установлена версия [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) не поддерживающая протокол SSL v.3

Варианта решения 2:

1. Обновить на устройстве OpenSSL (требуется рут)
2. Выключить поддержку SSL v.3 на стороне клиента (то бишь приложения) [android disable ssl v3](http://letmegooglethat.com/?q=android+disable+ssl+v3)

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ принял т.к. он наводит на решение. Но сам воспользовался ссылкой от ЮрийСПб