# Проблема с парсингом сайта с помощью Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

```
try {
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://bloknot-taganrog.ru").userAgent("Mozilla").timeout(5000).get();
   Element header = doc.select(".about .h1").first();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Несколько дней назад сайт перевели на https, и сайт перестал парситься. Другие https сайты парсятся без проблем. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Если ошибку выдаёт - приложите её лог. Без этого помочь нельзя никак

Comment: Вот что вернул e - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте в первую очередь попробовал бы делать запрос в сеть не либой для парсинга HTML, но либой для сетевых запросов. OkHttp, например. Это может помочь, т.к. в JSOUP может быть старая версия либы для сети, которая и выдаёт ошибку. Если это не поможет - то будет сложно, если вы не под Android делаете - там можно попробовать проблему в пару строк решить при наличии гугло-сервисов на девайсе.

Comment: именно под Android

Comment: Тогда попробуйте решение [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002766/retrofit2-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-sslhandshakeexception-sslprotocolexception/1002779#1002779). И в любом случае вам стоит перейти на OkHttp.

Comment: если там самоподписанный сертификат, то вот этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48278188/11771781) может помочь

Comment: Спасибо! Помог вот этот [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55531011/7044635)